# Swedish voice for Android's (Google's) Text-to-Speech?

Tags: android, text-to-speech, google-text-to-speech

I'm creating a navigation software for Android, and I'm going to use Android's `TextToSpeech` system (which I believe is the same as the *Google Text-to-Speech* system, therefore the `google-text-to-speech` tag) for "voice guidance".
I have a problem though.

The problem is that I need a Swedish speaking voice, because first of all, the app is mainly going to be used by Swedes in Sweden, and second, because of the Swedish road names, words, pronunciations (especially the characters *Å*, *Ä* and *Ö*) and so on, though I can't simply set the language to Swedish with `aTextToSpeechInstance.setLanguage(Locale.SWEDEN)` (or something alike) because there is no member representing Sweden in the `Locale` class.

I've Googled for it, but I can't seem to find anything.

I know Google Translate has a Swedish voice, and I'm pretty sure that the Android app is using the `TextToSpeech` system, but I can't seem to figure out how it is done...

When I list the available TTS'es on my device with `TextToSpeech.getEngines()` I see two engines. One is the default one, Google's TTS, and the second one is from a package called `com.svox.pico`. I've Googled for *SVOX*, and found that it has a Swedish voice, but I have three questions about it.

- Can I use this engine on EVERY phone compatible with the `TextToSpeech` system?
- How do I use it?
- How do I select the Swedish voice for it?

I wonder how I can make the Android TTS speak with a Swedish voice, so that it can pronounce Swedish words, characters, names etc.

If there is no way of doing it with the Android (Google) TTS, I am open to alternatives, but the one built into Android is the one which I prefer.

Notice that I use API level 15 as a minimum for the app, so a lot of the TTS methods aren't available.

Comment: What, exactly, is your question? Do you want to know how to use Google's TextToSpeech with Swedish? Or do you want to use `TextToSpeech.setLanguage(Locale.SWEDEN)`?

Comment: @jww My question is: How do I make the Android TTS system speak with a Swedish voice?

Comment: You don't need to rely on the limited selection of predefined `Locale` constants.  Have you tried `new Locale("sv", "SE")`?

Comment: @KevinKrumwiede No, I haven't. I'll try it tomorrow.

Comment: @KevinKrumwiede I tried this, but it doesn't work, but I've got it working with `Locale.US`, so the utility class that I made for the `TextToSpeech` system works. However, when calling `tts.getFeatures(locale)` after setting `locale` to `new Locale("sv", "SE")` returns `[networktts]`. Does this mean that I have to ask the user to download Swedish language for the TTS?

Comment: @TheDDestroyer12 Sounds like it.  Try installing it yourself and see if `getFeatures(...)` returns something different.

Comment: @KevinKrumwiede Unfortunately there is no alternative to install a Swedish voice in the Google TTS settings on my phone. I still wonder how Google Translate uses the Swedish voice... I think I'll try to contact Google and ask them for support. Thanks!

Comment: @TheDDestroyer12 [Ivona](http://www.ivona.com) offers a Swedish voice.

Comment: @KevinKrumwiede Thanks! That looks awesome! Would you like to post it as an answer too?

Comment: @TheDDestroyer12 I don't really understand all this stuff, just throwing out suggestions.  I've been holding off on posting it as an answer until I hit on something that works. :)

Comment: @KevinKrumwiede No problems. I'll do it myself when I've tried it out! Thanks! ;)

Answer (score 1):

I'm a bit late, but the problem also might be related to the fact that the standard Android TextToSpeech engine is not the same as the Google's one.
If I initialize `TextToSpeech` object without manually passing the TTS System, it cannot pronounce swedish words correctly (in case user haven't changed it in the device setitngs himself).

In my case this workes:

```
class SwedishSpeaker(
    private val context: Context
) : TextToSpeech.OnInitListener {

    val googleTtsPackage = "com.google.android.tts" // Google TTS Package

    private val textToSpeech = TextToSpeech(
        context,
        this,
        googleTtsPackage // passing Google TTS Package as the third parameter
    )

    override fun onInit(status: Int) {
        if (status == TextToSpeech.SUCCESS) {
            try {
                textToSpeech.language = Locale("sv", "SE")
                Log.d(TAG, "onInit: successful")
            } catch (e: Exception) {
                Log.d(TAG, "onInit: ${e.message}")
            }
        } else Log.d(TAG, "onInit: Language initialization failed")
    }

    fun speakWord(word: String) {
        textToSpeech.apply {
            stop()
            speak(word, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null)
        }
    }
}
```

Otherwise user will have to change TTS engine manually in device settings.
Thanks to this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/27471318/13828248